# Leibniz's 1684 Solution to De Beaune's Problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, math-history, geometric-series

In his 1684 text, "[A New Method for Finding Minima and Maxima](https://web.archive.org/web/20230521075545id_/http://17centurymaths.com/contents/Leibniz/nova1.pdf)," Leibniz solves an inverse-tangent problem posed by De Beaune that basically asks what kind of curve will have a constant subtangent (p. 8 in this translation) ([i.e. the subtangent will always have length a in the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgNaY.jpg)).

I understand that this is the same as asking for the solution to the differential equation:

$\frac{dw}{dx} = \frac{w}{a}$

which is an exponential function of the family:

$w = Ce^{x/a}$

where C is the initial value. This is equivalent to $x = a \log(\frac{w}{C})$.

What I don't understand is how to connect this solution to the way Leibniz actually solves the problem. Leibniz says that:

> that is if the x shall be in an arithmetic progression, the w
> shall be in a geometric progression, or if w shall be numbers, x will be their
> logarithms: therefore the line WW is logarithmic.

Leibniz shows that $x$ forms an arithmetic progression and $w$ forms a geometric progression with common ratio $(1 + \frac{b}{a})$:

$x, x + dx, x + 2dx,..., x + ndx$

For w, Leibniz lets $dx$ be a constant $b$

$\frac{a}{b}dw = {w}$

$w + dw = w + \frac{w}{a}dx = w + \frac{b}{a}w = w(1 + \frac{b}{a})$

We can write the $n$th term of this geometric progression as $W_n = W_0(1 + \frac{b}{a})^n$. If we let $W_0 = C$ and let $x = n$, can we obtain the equation $x = a \log(\frac{w}{C})$ from this equation for the geometric sequence itself?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could connect a pdf containing a translation of Leibniz's text, and indicate what page you are quoting from.

Comment: @MikhailKatz "It would be helpful if you connect a pdf containing a translation of Leibniz's text" Click on the first link. I agree with your second phrase though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't let $x=n$ because $n$ is supposed to be infinite, whereas $x$ is finite.

Assuming for simplicity that $x$ ranges through $[0,1]$, we obtain that $b=dx=\frac1n$.
Therefore in your notation, $W_n = W_0 \big(1+ \frac{a^{-1}}{n}\big)^n\approx W_0 \, e^{1/a}$, where $\approx$ is the relation of infinite proximity.  Note that Leibniz routinely dropped negligible terms in his calculations.

Comment: @KamalSaleh, Why?  The symbols $\approx$ and $\simeq$ are routinely used for the relation of infinite proximity.  The symbol $\sim$ tends to have a different meaning.

Comment: @KamalSaleh, in the context of infinitesimal analysis, Robert Goldblatt uses $\simeq$ for the relation of infinite proximity; see e.g., page 52 in Goldblatt, Robert.  Lectures on the hyperreals.  An introduction to
nonstandard analysis.  Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 188.
Springer-Verlag, New York, 1998.

Comment: $W_0 \big(1+ \frac{a^{-1}}{n}\big)^n\approx W_0e^{-a}$ looks wrong. I'd say: $W_0 \big(1- \frac{a}{n}\big)^n\approx W_0e^{-a}\,.$

Comment: @KurtG., The number $e$ is the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac1n)^n$.  For all
$t$ there is a similar limit formula
$e^t=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{t}{n})^n$.  There are two equivalent
definitions of limit: the $\epsilon,N$ definition, or alternatively
via the the [standard
part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_part_function), namely as
the standard part of $(1+\frac{t}{n})^n$ for an infinite $n$.  The
latter definition may be closer to the procedures of Leibniz and Euler; see [recent work on Leibniz and
Euler](https://u.math.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/leibniz.html).

Comment: @KurtG., Thanks, corrected.

Comment: @MikhailKatz isn't $W_0e^{-a}$ just a constant like $a$ and $W_0$? Do we set $dx = \frac{1}{n}$ because it is an infinitesimal? Why does x have to range through [0, 1]?

Comment: @MrMagoo, it's not $e^{-1}$ but $e^{1/a}$.